# What sites are good for peer reviewed analysis?

Tags: discussion

[My answer](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/30459/in-literate-countries-does-more-education-lead-to-more-economic-growth/30463#30463) was (correctly) deleted as it is original analysis rather than cited / peer reviews analysis.

> Hi Tim. **This is an extensive analysis - Original Research that needs a decent peer review.** Unfortunately, this isn't the place for that. I hate to have to do this, given the effort you have put into this, but Skeptics.SE is not the place to perform science, it is the place to report what science has found.

Emphasis mine. My question is - where could I get this peer reviewed? I understand why it was deleted (and it was right to do so) but I'd be interested in it being analysed.

Where should I go for this?

Comment: My guess is that you can write an academic paper and write your original research there, and try to publish it in an academic journal. Usually, you can ask college professors who will help you.

Comment: @GeorgeChalhoub I'm 17, I'm not at University. I'm also not doing statistics, so I don't know anyone specifically to help. I don't know if my School has any advice on this.

Comment: You can try [economics.se]. Kudos for asking for help instead of getting angry. We need more users like you!

Comment: @Sklivvz been on the network for long enough to know that that gets downvotes and nowhere (e.g. SO Meta). Thanks for the suggestion. I knew it was a risky answer when I posted so not too upset about it.